# Full Calendar External Events List

Tags: php, mysql, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to load all my events that have a null for the start date into my external events list, which I can do, using PHP inside of an div tag to accomplish.

Unassigned.php

```
<?php

//load.php
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM install WHERE date_assigned IS NULL";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
?>
```

Then this inside my html file

```
<div id='external-events'>

      <h4>Draggable Events</h4>

      <div id='external-events-list'>

        <?php while($result = $statement->fetch()): ?>
          <div class='fc-event'><?= $result['Customer']?></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>



    </div>
```

The issue I'm having is this does not hold my id for the database making it impossible to update.   I can also pass the php to json format.

```
<?php

//load.php
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM install WHERE date_assigned IS NULL";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["Job"],
  'title'   => $row["Customer"],
  'start'   => $row["date_assigned"]
 );
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

My thoughts are it would be simpler to pass the json values into a loop to create my list, I'm just unsure of how to do that.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
I've decided to use the php file to create my json data as that seems to be what FullCalendar uses.  I'm reading the file like this, which works perfectly for looping through it and pulling the title and putting it where I want it.  But I cannot seem to get it to attach the id to it for some reason.  Anyone point me in the right direction?

```
   window.onload = function() {
  $.getJSON( "calendar/unassigned.php", function(Data2) {
    var tmp = '';
    $.each(Data2, function(key, value){
      tmp += '  <div class="fc-event" data="{title:"'+value.title+'"}"id="'+value.id+'">';
      tmp += value.title;
      tmp += '  </div>';
    });
    $('#cgMain').prepend(tmp);
    $('#calendar-events .fc-event').each(function(event) {
    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      id: value.id,
     // id: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });
    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI

  });
  });
}
```

Comment: Put the ID into a data-attribute of the draggable element, so you can retrieve it later

Comment: I've tried doing this, however, I cannot seem to recall the attribute in the proper place.

Comment: You want to be aiming for something like this in your HTML: `<div class='fc-event' data-id='123'>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar has a built in function to drag external DOM elements over the calendar itself and add an event with the source DOM element's data.

In HTML:

```
 <div id='external-events'>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
</div>
```

And the JS code:

```
var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');

new Draggable(containerEl, {
    itemSelector: '.fc-event',
    eventData: function(eventEl) {
       return {
          title: eventEl.innerText
       };
    }
});
```

See the manual and the codepen here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging

Comment: I have tried this, which lead me down my first option of loading the results of my php query into the div tags.  It looped through everything fine it just didn't pass anything but the title along.

Comment: Title is just an example, you can stick watever you want in an event object. You can add data-mydataname="something" to your DOM elements, then retrieve it like  event.myData = eventEl.dataset.mydataname. Special values will be stored in  event.extendedProps.myData

Comment: I believe the problem to be that the event data is not being sent when I prepend the div tag itself.  I'm going to have to do more research as obviously coding is not my strong point.